# Using Instagram API with Python in non sandbox mode

Tags: python-3.x, instagram

I was writing a Python script which can access info from Instagram, and display it on a terminal.

Example info like:

1. list of users who liked that picture
2. list of new followers
3. list of users who unfollowed

I wrote my script but my client was in sandbox mode, so i couldn't access the data of other users, i do not want to publish any app, website but i just want that script to work for myself, is there any way to get out of sandbox mode and make complete use of Instagram API.